# Change text effects in PowerPoint

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I want to change text effects in PowerPoint, specifically Glow effect.

I have about ~2500 PowerPoint files with 1-15 slides in each, and I need to change the text to have a text glow effect (not shape glow effect).

I thought the easiest approach would be to create a macro, however I couldn't find a way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a starting point for the glow part:

Pass a reference to the shape containing the text to this sub; edit the radius, color and transparency to suit.

Sub GlowTheTextIn(oSh As Shape)
    With oSh.TextFrame2.TextRange
        With .Font.Glow
            .Radius = 25
            .Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
            .Transparency = 0.5
        End With
    End With
End Sub

This will give you a starting point for doing something to each presentation in a folder, each slide in a presentation, each shape on a slide:

Do something to -- every shape on a slide, every slide in a presentation, every presentation in a folder
http://www.pptfaq.com/FAQ00594_Do_something_to_--_every_shape_on_a_slide-_every_slide_in_a_presentation-_every_presentation_in_a_folder.htm